# Is there a command-line and non-RDP way to logoff a Windows XP PRO user remotely from a Linux box?

Tags: linux, windows

I've been trying "net rpc shutdown" but it only works for rebooting and halting. RDP doesn't fit my needs. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

use [winexe](https://lbtwiki.cern.ch/bin/view/Online/WinExe) it is ps-exec alike program that works under linux. i use it to invoke some actions on few windows boxes from linux.

Answer (score 0):

How about WINE and <strike>shutdown.exe -l?</strike> -l can't be used with -m (the command to target a remote PC). You could, however force a reboot which would have nearly the same effect: "shutdown.exe /m [computername], -f -r"

WINE and PsShutdown... in fact the whole suite of PsTools would probably be good to have, but I digress...